# Python/Regex: Get all strings between any two characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a use case that requires the identification of many different pieces of text between any two characters.

For example,

1. String between a single space and `(`: `def test()` would return
   `test`
2. String between a word and space (`paste`), and a special character (`/`): `@paste "game_01/01"` would return `"game_01`
3. String between a single space and `(` with multiple target strings: `} def test2() { Hello(x, 1)` would return `test2` and `Hello`

To do this, I'm attempting to write something generic that will identify the shortest string between any two characters.

My current approach is (from **chrisz**):

```
pattern = '{0}(.*?){1}'.format(re.escape(separator_1), re.escape(separator_2))
```

And for the first use case, `separator_1 = \s` and `separator_2 = (`. This isn't working so evidently I am missing something but am not sure what.

**tl;dr** How can I write a generic regex to parse the shortest string between any two characters?

- Note: I know there are many examples of this but they seem quite specific and I'm looking for a general solution if possible.

Comment: What does _"This isn't working"_ mean exactly? Is there an error message? Does it not produce the output you expected?

Comment: this is not a free coding service, a free tutorial service or a free design service.

Comment: @Aran-Fey it doesn't produce what I'm hoping for. For instance, a space will be include before the target string, sometimes characters (e.g. ` test`) characters after the string will be included (e.g. `test()`)

Comment: Do you have to use regex? Why not write a simple function?

Comment: @FatihAkici actually I don't have to but thought that this would be simpler, more generic and also curious to see what the solution would be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for:

```
import re

def smallest_between_two(a, b, text):
    return min(re.findall(re.escape(a)+"(.*?)"+re.escape(b),text), key=len)

print(smallest_between_two(' ', '(', 'def test()'))
print(smallest_between_two('[', ']', '[this one][not this one]'))
print(smallest_between_two('paste ', '/', '@paste "game_01/01"'))
```

Output:

```
test
this one
"game_01
```

To add an explanation to what this does:

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings

[`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

> Escape all the characters in pattern except ASCII letters and numbers. This is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it

[`(.*?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ROUz6j/1)

> `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

So our regular expression matches any character (not including line terminators) between two arbitrary escaped strings, and then returns the shortest length string from the `list` that `re.findall()` returns.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when there's multiple expressions on the same line but I believe I can work around this. It seems like `re.escape` was the thing that I was missing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean, when there are multiple expressions on the same line?

Comment: For instance, `def test() hello()` will only get `test` and not `hello`. Possibly due to the `min` over `len`

Comment: Your question is: Shortest string between two characters.  Hello is not the shortest string between `' '` and `(`. If you remove the `min` you will get all strings that match the criteria.

Comment: Use this: `return re.findall(re.escape(a)+"(.*?)"+re.escape(b),text)` if you want all matches.

Comment: That's what I've currently made the change too. Here is an exact example, `'def test() { Hello(0)`, this will give `['test', '{ Hello']`

Comment: ignore the `]` at the end of the result in the comment above

Comment: I'm confused as to what the issue is.  Do you want to also match matches inside of other matches?

Comment: My aim for any string is to find all substrings that are between two characters. So for the example, `def test() { Hello(0)` I would want `['test', 'Hello']` if the two separators are a single whitespace and `(`. Sorry I noticed that the `shortest` requirement was confusing so I've corrected this

Comment: So you don't want to include characters that are not alphanumeric? Because `{ Hello` is a string that occurs between `' '` and `'('`

Comment: Unfortunately not. Here's a similar example, `} def test2() { Hello(x, 1)` this will produce `} def test2', '{ Hello`. So it's quite tricky.